# Single method executer and error handler

Tags: c#, .net

I've written what I initially thought was a generic method executer and error handler for any method I add or might add in the future but after many hours of struggling and googling, I have resorted to going to forums.

Aim: To try and get away from individual error handling in a method and handle all errors in one single method. (hope this makes sense).

Code for Generic method executer and error handler:

```
    internal static Tuple<SystemMessage, object> ExecuteAndHandleAnyErrors<T,TArg1>(this object callingMethod, params object[] args)
    {
        dynamic methodToExecute;

        if (callingMethod.GetType() == typeof(Func<T, TArg1>))
        {
            methodToExecute = (callingMethod as Func<T,TArg1>);
        }
        else
        {
            methodToExecute = (callingMethod as Action<T, TArg1>);
        }

        try
        {
            var result = methodToExecute.DynamicInvoke(args);
            return new Tuple<SystemMessage, object>(null,result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Tuple<SystemMessage, object>(new SystemMessage
            {
                MessageText = ex.Message,
                MessageType = SystemMessage.SystemMessageType.Error
            }, null);
        }
    }

//This is the code for a sample method:

internal QuestionAnswerSet LoadQuestions(DataWrapper dataWrapper)
{
   var taskExecuter = new Func<DataWrapper, QuestionAnswerSet> (InternalDeserializeObject<QuestionAnswerSet>);

   var questionAnswerSet = taskExecuter.ExecuteAndHandleAnyErrors<DataWrapper, QuestionAnswerSet>(dataWrapper);          

   return questionAnswerSet.Item2 as QuestionAnswerSet;
}
```

my question is this: Is it possible that if the LoadQuestions method falls over, how do I catch the error and defer the error handling to the ExecuteAndHandleAnyErrors method without manually adding a try...catch statement to the LoadQuestions method?

Hope this makes sense.

thank u.
charles

Comment: Looks quite complicated. I do the same using lambda expressions:`ExecuteAndHandleAnyErrors` has the only parameter `Action`, and I pass to it any code written in a lambda body.

Comment: Well, it should work, except that it's going to hide the exception you're trying to catch inside `TargetInvocationException`. You have to get the inner exception of that to get the "real" one.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap every call of `LoadQuestions` in its own call to `ExecuteAndHandleAnyErrors`.

However, this seems to be missing part of the point of exception handling. When using exceptions to communicate error, one usually doesn't "handle all errors in one single method". That one single method usually cannot deal with any possible exception sensibly. For example, could your method handle a `ThreadAbortedException`? What about an `ArgumentException`? Nor does one add a lot of `try ... catch` block all over the place.

In general, try to write `try ... catch` blocks that handle specific exceptions when your code can handle the failure sensibly (e.g., catching `FileNotFoundException` near where you open a file and triggering a dialog box or attempting to open a default file at a different path).

Often, an application will have one top-level `try ... catch` block in `Main()` to log any otherwise unhandled exceptions. Then it rethrows the exception/crashes the program/exits the program.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
What I was doing was is seeing the first time the exception is thrown and not stepping further down by pressing F10.

THanks for all the help